# IntelliJ and Spring boot test: unresolved bean, could not autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have got a gradle imported project in IntelliJ, kotlin. Compilations go fine, tests are run fine both via command line and via IntelliJ. The only thing I'd like gone is the red error highlighting saying e.g. "Could not autowire. No beans of 'FooRepository' type found". The weird part is that I've got exact same setup in another PC and there it works fine. Using IntelliJ `2021.1` on Ubuntu. I can't recall this in the previous versions.

[image]

The `FooRepository` is declared with `@Repository` annotation, like this:

```
@Repository
class FooTypeRepository(
    @Autowired var jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
){...}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: Yes, many times. Also restarted, didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, resolved it by deleting `.idea` folder and reimporting the project. Sometimes IntelliJ just need to reimport and reindex everything.

Answer (score -1):

Your class FooRepository needs to be a Spring Bean. It has to have some annotation indicating that it's a bean. For example annotation @Repository or just @Component.

Comment: It is declared with `@Repository` annotation. Updated the question @alan